# Nuget Package won't install in UAP

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to create a custom nuget package out of one of my projects. When I try to install it into the test project that references it, I receive this error:

Package "package" 1.0.5 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063). Package "package" 1.0.5 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)

This obviously isn't the case because the test project can run fine referencing the Project itself.

I'm building the nuget package based on my nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Project</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>Project</title>
    <authors>company</authors>
    <owners>company</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>desc</description>
    <copyright>cp</copyright>
    <dependencies>
       <group targetFramework="uap ">
        <dependency id="Logging" version="1.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.NETCore" version="5.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility" version="1.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="NuGet.Build" version="2.12.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="NuGet.CommandLine" version="4.1.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\*.dll" target="lib" />
  </files>
```

"Logging" is also a custom nuget package I created from the .csproj file of another project.

I've tried removing the  tag, and also tried renaming the targetFramework="uap", none of that works.

What could be wrong and what can I try to get this working?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, I am facing a very similar problem

Comment: @Corcus It's not a complete answer, but I found a workaround. I recommend posting a bug in the nuget project home. They are fairly responsive. So the new version of Nuget is supposed to be built off of the project file, and not a nuspec file. Doing this fixed the problem for me. It doesn't always do everything right, but one thing it does do is solve this issue. There are other problems with doing it this way, but I was able to solve those with other workarounds. What a mess ;)

Answer (score 0):

The target doesn't just rely on the NuSpec file, it would depend on the C# project and the dll itself. Go to:

> Project> Rightclick> Properties> TargetFramework>

Set it to .Net or whatever. Also, change your output type to a console application rather than a windows application, if that is doable.

Also, you should create the nuspec file using:

> Nuget spec < ProjectPath >

This gives us the advantage to just change the metadata for .csproj files, and copies that into the package metadata automatically.

I'm not a 100% sure if this will fix it, but this should be what needs to be done. Best of luck!

Comment: This didn't do it for me, no matter where I set the target to the right framework I always had this problem.